# Merging and mixing two list of list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of list of dictionaries :

```
liste = [[{"template_id": 32, "template_name" : "test1"}, {"template_id": 33, "template_name" : "test2"}],[{"template_id": 34, "template_name" : "test3"}, {"template_id": 35, "template_name" : "test4"},{"template_id": 36, "template_name" : "test5"}]]
```

I want to merge them like this :

```
[{"template_id": 32, "template_name" : "test1"},{"template_id": 34, "template_name" : "test3"}, {"template_id": 33, "template_name" : "test2"},{"template_id": 35, "template_name" : "test4"},{"template_id": 36, "template_name" : "test5"}]
```

I have tried to do it like this but it does not work properly since i'm not a Python expert :

```
for j in range(len(liste)):
    for i in range(len(liste[j])+1):
            try :
                print(f"F={f},j={j}, i={i} ")
                optimized_list.append(liste[i][j])
                #print(liste[i][j]['template_name'])
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

EDIT :

To be more clear the output i want is the following :

```
[{"template_id": 32, "template_name" : "test1"},
 {"template_id": 34, "template_name" : "test3"},
 {"template_id": 33, "template_name" : "test2"},
 {"template_id": 35, "template_name" : "test4"},
 {"template_id": 36, "template_name" : "test5"}]
```

Comment: whatcha tryin to do again? I guess you want a single `dict` object, unless im totally shooting way past left field on this?

Comment: use `.extend` instead of `.append` and remove `[j]`, then you add not a list of values, but several values and will have what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy`, and use `concatenate()` function and `flat` attribute to get your desired result.

```
import numpy 

liste = [[{"template_id": 32, "template_name" : "test1"}, 
        {"template_id": 34, "template_name" : "test2"}],[{"template_id": 
        34, "template_name" : "test3"}, {"template_id": 35, 
        "template_name" : "test4"},{"template_id": 36, "template_name" : 
        "test5"}]]

flat_list = list(numpy.concatenate(liste).flat)

print(flat_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```py
from itertools import chain

liste = [[{"template_id": 32, "template_name" : "test1"}, {"template_id": 34, "template_name" : "test2"}],[{"template_id": 34, "template_name" : "test3"}, {"template_id": 35, "template_name" : "test4"},{"template_id": 36, "template_name" : "test5"}]]

output = [*chain.from_iterable(liste)]
print(output)
# [{'template_id': 32, 'template_name': 'test1'},
#  {'template_id': 34, 'template_name': 'test2'},
#  {'template_id': 34, 'template_name': 'test3'},
#  {'template_id': 35, 'template_name': 'test4'},
#  {'template_id': 36, 'template_name': 'test5'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think i was not clear, the idea is to mix the list also. i have edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extend()` and then simply `shuffle()` it:

```
import random

new_list = []
for i in liste:
    new_list.extend(i)

random.shuffle(new_list)
print(new_list)
```

The output is:

```
[{'template_id': 32, 'template_name': 'test1'}, 
 {'template_id': 34, 'template_name': 'test3'}, 
 {'template_id': 36, 'template_name': 'test5'}, 
 {'template_id': 35, 'template_name': 'test4'}, 
 {'template_id': 33, 'template_name': 'test2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found something which seem to work :

```py
liste = [[{ "template_name" : "test1" , "silo" : "1"}, { "template_name" : "test2", "silo" : "1"}],[{ "template_name" : "test3", "silo" : "2"}, { "template_name" : "test4", "silo" : "2"},{ "template_name" : "test5", "silo" : "2"}]]

optimized_list = []

while len(liste) != 0 :
    for i in liste :
        if len(i) == 1 :
            optimized_list.append(i.pop())
            liste.remove(i)
        else :
            optimized_list.append(i.pop())
                
print(optimized_list)
```

I pop items and do a simpler list with no index like i did before.
It returns this :

```
[{'template_name': 'test2', 'silo': '1'}, {'template_name': 'test5', 'silo': '2'}, {'template_name': 'test1', 'silo': '1'}, {'template_name': 'test4', 'silo': '2'}, {'template_name': 'test3', 'silo': '2'}]
```

It's not perfect, but it works like a charm in my use case. The idea is to launch some jobs on different server at once to spread the load on every server instead of only one.

I launch one job on server A, one on server B and so on..

Thanks for all your idea it has helped me a lot.